# Switching Profile routes based on user role in registration (Express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, mern, express-router

**A bit of a long read**

I am currently building the backend for a MERN project, with quite an interesting structure (I would be changing the specifics because it is a private project).

- Database: There are 4 database schemas at the moment, 1 user schema with 3 different roles: student, teacher, and sponsor.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username : {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
   email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
   }, 
   password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
},
role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['student', 'teacher', 'sponsor'],  
    required: true,
},
dateCreated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
})

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema)
```

**The 3 types of user roles have their own unique but quite similar profile schema (TeacherProfile, StudentProfile e.t.c)  which all  reference the user shcema by ID **.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const studentProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   user: {
       // create a reference to the user schema
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'user'
   },.........
```

- I have an authentication middleware that takes care of the jwt logic.

**Now things get interesting at the routes**

- I have a user route that takes care of user registration
- An auth route for login and authentication,
- And 3 routes for the profiles

What I desire to build is a middleware logic that would switch between the 3 project routes once a user registers, so he/she would be returned the profile that desribes choosen role during registration.

keep in mind that there are calls to the database, which i have to wrap inside of an async block

This is an example of one of such routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const config = require('config');
// validator
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
// auth middleware
const auth = require('../../middleware/authMiddleware');

// db collections
const SponsorProfile = require('../../models/SponsorProfile');
const User = require('../../models/User');

// @route   GET api/SponsorProfile/me
// @desc    GET current user profile
// @access  Private 
router.get('/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
   try {
       // fetch profile object
       const sponsorProfile = await SponsorProfile.findOne({user:req.user.id});
       // check if profile exists
       if(!sponsorProfile) {
           return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Hello Sponsor, You have not created a profile'})
       }
       res.json(sponsorProfile)
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error.message);
       res.status(500).json({msg:'This is our fault not yours'})
   }
})


module.exports= router;
```

**Now this is what I tried:**

- I built a master router that uses all the profile routers as sub-routers starting from the student to the sponsor.

```
const express = require('express');
const profilesRouter = express.Router();

profilesRouter.use('/', require('./studentProfile'));
profilesRouter.use('/', require('./teacherProfile'));
profilesRouter.use('/', require('./sponsorProfile'));

module.exports = profilesRouter;
```

- It is then called in server.js like this:

```
app.use('/api/profilesRouter', require('./routes/api/profilesRouter'));
```

- The appraoch was to place a middleware function in the first 2 routers and leave the third one empty so there will be a switch, if the criterias in the first two passes.

```
    async function shouldRouterChange(req, res, next) {
        let userRole = await User.findOne({user:req.role}).select('-password');
        console.log(userRole)
        if ( userRole === 'mentor') {
     return next('router');
        }
        return next();
    }
     function shouldRouterChange(req, res, next) {
        if (req.user.role === 'teacher') {
            return next('router');
        }
        return next();
    }

// @route   GET api/studentProfile/me
// @desc    GET current user profile
// @access  Private 
router.get('/me', [auth, shouldRouterChange], async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // check if profile exists
        const studentProfile = await StudentProfile.findOne({user:req.user.id}).populate('user', ['role']);
        if(!studentProfile) {
            return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Hello student, You have not created a profile'})
        }
        res.json(studentProfile)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(500).json({msg:'This is our fault not yours'})
    }
})

module.exports= router;
```

**Obviously that did not work**

- Then I tried the middleware function like this

```
    async function shouldRouterChange(req, res, next) {
        let userRole = await User.findOne({user:req.role}).select('-password');
        console.log(userRole)
        if ( userRole === 'mentor') {
     return next('router');
        }
        return next();
    }
```

**No Way**

Then this:

```
    async function shouldRouterChange(req, res, next) {

        try {
            let userRole = await studentProfile.findOne({user:req.user.id}).populate('user', ['role']);
            // conditional
           console.log(userRole)
            if (userRole.role==='mentor') {
                return next('router')
           }
             return next()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message)
            res.status(500).json({msg: 'Server Error'})
        }
        
    }
```

I debugged as best as I could and realized that:

1. The whole switching structure actually works nicely
2. The problem lies in the middleware structure
3. The first middleware structure might be corerct, apart from the conditional.
4. The conditional equates to null, or undefined (it does not get the user role properly).
5. The whole middleware logic might have to be called inside the `router.get()` logic that returns the profile.

**My question is how can i make the conditional correct, and consequently structure the middleware to work properly (maybe without doing too much change on my app structure, won't mind anyways)**

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the error, and it works like a charm

To use router level middleware for switching routers (can also switch single routes)

1. Build a master router for all those routers (now sub-routers):

```
const express = require('express');
const profilesRouter = express.Router();

profilesRouter.use('/', require('./studentProfile'));
profilesRouter.use('/', require('./teacherProfile'));
profilesRouter.use('/', require('./sponsorProfile'));

module.exports = profilesRouter;
```

2. Add the master router path to server.js:

```
     app.use('/api/profileRouter', require('./routes/api/profileRouter'));
```

3. Build the middleware logic, to switch the routers conditionally:

> Middleware to switch from student to teacher router file:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

// Check user profile
function teacherSwitch(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  //  if no token is returned
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, permission denied' });
  }

  try {
    // decode token
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
    // set role to the same value as in the request
    req.user.role = decoded.user.role;
    // check if role is teacher
    if (decoded.user.role !== 'student') {
      return next('router');
    }
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Wrong token, authentication failed' });
  }
}

module.exports = teacherSwitch;
```

Our logic here is to switch based on the role chosen by the user when registering. This means that role is a DB field in the user schema.
All we have to do is to add the role in our authentication payload.
A token is created on user registration, and that token uses the user id as payload, so if we add the role to that payload, we can now access it in the "req" object and build our conditional around it.

> This payload is located in my auth route using the auth middleware:

```
   // create jwt payload
    const payload = await {

      user: {
        id: user.id,
        role: user.role,
      },
    };
    // if user login is successful, return token
    jwt.sign(payload, config.get('jwtSecret'),
      { expiresIn: 36000 }, (error, token) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.json({ token });
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
```

Also, the "next(router)" in the middleware function is the magic that switches to the next router in the router stack found in profilesRouter.
It initiates a switch which is then called when we finally return next.

```
 return next().
```

4. Call the teacherSwitch middleware in the first sub-router (student router)

```
router.get('/me', [auth, teacherSwitch], async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // check if profile exists
    const studentProfile = await StudentProfile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
    if (!teacherProfile) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Hello student, You have not created a profile' });
    }
    return res.json(studentProfile);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'This is our fault not yours' });
  }
});
```

5. Create another middleware to switch to the 3rd sub-router conditionally

```
function sponsorSwitch(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
  
    //  if no token is returned
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, permission denied' });
    }
  
    try {
      // decode token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
      // set role to the same value as in the request
      req.user.role = decoded.user.role;
      // check if role is partner
      if (decoded.user.role !== 'teacher') {
        return next('router');
      }
      return next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Wrong token, authentication failed' });
    }
  }
```

6 Call it in the second sub-router.

```
router.get('/me', [auth, partnerSwitch], async (req, res) => ...
```

And that is it, as long as the condition is not met, it will switch and switch until the condition is passed.
Works just like a regular switch statement.

What I was missing here was that to be able to use the role to switch, I had to call it in as part of the auth payload, this way it becomes part of the request object in the req, res cycle, and hence can be manipulated as you like.

We never need to call another middleware in the last router, because logically the switching only gets there when everything fails, just like the default in a regular switch statement.

**N.B:** It is actually important to call the middleware function in the last router, as this would make this work perfectly in the frontend (I used react), not doing this caused bug where react could not return the last route if it had to, which is not what we want.

> Got some very valuable help from  [John](https://twitter.com/AuMayeung)

> An used this  [site](https://jwt.io/) to manually decode my JWT tokens, to know exactly what was going on.